# Shimano Bottom Bracket alternative

Tags: bottom-bracket

I have a Giant TCR Alliance which has had 2 Shimano SM-BB71-41 press fit bottom brackets, both started clicking, pretty annoying. Any ideas on a good alternative? I'm looking to the £60 mark. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4):

There's every reason to suspect that problems with the bore tolerances and/or alignment are causing it. That's become a common theme of creaky BB issues.

It's a good idea when the cups are out to take what measurements you can to see what's going on. Bore tolerances are easy to measure but alignment for the most part is not.

The [thread-together](https://wheelsmfg.com/bottom-brackets/bb86-92/bb86-92-outboard-abec-3-bb-for-24mm-shimano-cranks-black.html) models from various manufacturers can sometimes help mitigate the effects of misalignment. Either retaining compound or, in some cases, very light abrasive work in the hands of someone who knows what they're doing can help with tolerances.

At the far end of the spectrum are the custom-for-your-frame's-misalignment BBs a la Hambini which can solve bore alignment problems that nothing else can.

Comment: We also shouldn't rule out the way they where installed. OP hasn't said how the BBs where installed, ie correctly and with all the usual anti-creak options.